# Looping over *args resets counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on some made up code to try to understand `*args` functionality and am having difficulty getting my `counter` variable to not reset.

After the 4th item, the numbering resets back to 0, but I want it to continue across the args.

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon']
lst2 = ['apple2', 'banana2', 'orange2', 'lemon2']
lst3 = ['apple3', 'banana3', 'orange3', 'lemon3']


def generateMenu(*args):
    counter = 0

    for i in args:
        def recurse(l, counter):
            for i in l:
                counter += 1
                if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                    recurse(i, counter)
                else:
                    print("{}. {}.".format(counter, i))
        recurse(i, counter)


generateMenu(lst, lst2, lst3)
```

**Output:**

```
1. apple.
2. banana.
3. orange.
4. lemon.
1. apple2.
2. banana2.
3. orange2.
4. lemon2.
1. apple3.
2. banana3.
3. orange3.
4. lemon3.
```

Comment: You're never giving a second argument to recurse. I'd expect that to be an error though. Also, the fact that you're shadowing the counter variable is probably causing off behavior. Make the parameter and variable different names.

Comment: What about using a global counter? First define outside your function `counter = 0`, then replace the first line of your function to `global counter`

Comment: @Carcigenicate He *is* passing `counter` in the *outer* call to `recurse`, just not in the *inner* one. And the inner case happens to never be triggered with the given input.

Comment: @deceze Right, I forgot it's interpreted so that error won't show immediately.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I rarely write Python and completely forgot that `global` was a necessary thing. I think someone else will be able to give you a much more authoritative answer than mine. This is almost definitely due to you shadowing your variable with the parameter though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for catching that. I've updated the code after testing it out since the issue still persists. I felt at first that returning the counter might help but it just kills the loop.

Comment: @Mikael Tried global as well. No change.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe Your updated code looks identical. The variable and parameter still have the same name. As deceze pointed out, your inner function never actually calls itself, so that change won't do anything. The problen is the names being the same, and the lack of `global` (unless that isn't required for inner functions).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm by no means an expert on Python, but I would've thought the variable names in different scopes would have no issues other than suffering readability. Nonetheless, I changed them and the issue persists, so it may be `global` but as mentioned above to Mikael, I've not had any luck in how I've implemented it.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe If they had different names, you wouldn't have been able to accidentally change the inner version without realizing it. It would have made the issue much clearer faster. I would have expected using `global` to access the outer variable to fix it though once you changed the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `counter` a `nonlocal` (nonlocal was introduced in Python3)

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon']
lst2 = ['apple2', 'banana2', 'orange2', 'lemon2']
lst3 = ['apple3', 'banana3', 'orange3', 'lemon3']


def generateMenu(*args):
    counter = 0

    for i in args:
        def recurse(l):
            nonlocal counter
            for i in l:
                counter += 1
                if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                    recurse(i)
                else:
                    print("{}. {}.".format(counter, i))
        recurse(i)


generateMenu(lst, lst2, lst3)
```

Alternatively, return `counter` from `recurse`

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon']
lst2 = ['apple2', 'banana2', 'orange2', 'lemon2']
lst3 = ['apple3', 'banana3', 'orange3', 'lemon3']

def generateMenu(*args):
    counter = 0

    for i in args:
        def recurse(l, counter):
            for i in l:
                counter += 1
                if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                    counter = recurse(i, counter)
                else:
                    print("{}. {}.".format(counter, i))
            return counter
        counter = recurse(i, counter)


generateMenu(lst, lst2, lst3)
```

Comment: Perfect. Tried both without issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `recurse` function is not aware of your `counter` from upper scope. So what you are increasing in each `for i in l:` loop is just the "inner" `counter` variable.

Your example might confuse you because you are using same variable names twice (`counter` and `i`). Try to rename them in a different way and you might get a better idea of what is happening with your code.

Comment: How might I `return` it to outer scope without breaking the loop?

Comment: It's either defining `global/nonlocal` or passing your outer `counter` to your `recurse` function and add it to inner counter in each loop or assigning a function to variable and returning, like in John La Rooy's example.

Answer (score 1):

Python has slightly odd rules about writing to variables outside of the function's scope. The easiest way to avoid this IMO is just to make sure that your recursive function returns the counter value at each state. I've slightly refactored to make it a bit clearer what is going on.

```
lst = [('apple', 'banana'), 'orange', 'lemon']
lst2 = ['apple2', 'banana2', 'orange2', 'lemon2']
lst3 = ['apple3', 'banana3', 'orange3', 'lemon3']


def generateMenu(*args):
    outer_counter = 1

    def recurse(l, inner_counter):
        for i in l:
            if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                inner_counter = recurse(i, inner_counter)
            else:
                print("{}. {}.".format(inner_counter, i))
                inner_counter += 1
        return inner_counter

    for i in args:
        outer_counter = recurse(i, outer_counter)


generateMenu(lst, lst2, lst3)
```